# Redirect of www to non-www works works for all URLs except the root

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following code in my Apache htaccess file that is used to redirect all www URLs to non-www URLs on wordpress. This works for all URLs except the root.

For example, http://www.noshon.it/recipes redirects properly to http://noshon.it/recipes. However, http://www.noshon.it incorrectly redirects to http://noshon.it/wordpress (where it receives a 404 page).

I can't figure out why all ULRs work except for the root. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
RewriteEngine On   
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.noshon\.it$ [NC]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://noshon.it/$1 [R=301,L]  
RewriteBase /  
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Where is the htaccess file located?

Comment: I think the redirect is somewhere in your php or otherwise somewhere else in your apache congig, as the only rule you have that would return a 301 is the RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://noshon.it/$1 [R=301,L]  but that wouldn't add "wordpress" to your url

Comment: also why are you double escaping the dot chars? Use a single backslash, otherwise a double backslash escapes to a literal backslash character

Comment: btw cool site, have to try some of those recipes :)

Comment: @JonLin I'm using a Bitnami image to host on EC2. The folder structure is /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs, where the htdocs folder contains Wordpress core files and themes. The .htaccess file is in the htdocs folder.

Comment: @WebChemist you were right about the redirect happening somewhere else. I looked in a wordpress.conf file located in /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/ and noticed a rule in that file doing the rewrite. I'll post the answer below. Thank you for your help! I'm glad you like the site :)

Comment: @WebChemist also to answer your question about double escaping the dot chars - I'm only single escaping but extra slashes were added when I pasted in stackoverflow. I'll try to edit the snippet above.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @WebChemist for suggesting that the redirect was happening in another file. I located a file named wordpress.conf in the /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/ directory of the Bitnami EC2 instance. This file had the following code:

```
# App url moved to root
DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs"
#Alias /wordpress/ "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/"
#Alias /wordpress "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs"

<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs">
    Options Indexes MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteBase /wordpress/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
<//Directory>

# Uncomment the following lines to see your application in the root
# of your URL. This is not compatible with more than one application.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/$ /wordpress/ [PT]
```

The rewrite was occurring in the last line of this file:

```
RewriteRule ^/$ /wordpress/ [PT]
```

I modified this file to the following and the redirects are working now:

```
# App url moved to root
DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs"
#Alias /wordpress/ "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/"
#Alias /wordpress "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs"

<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs">
    Options Indexes MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteBase /wordpress/
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
<//Directory>

# Uncomment the following lines to see your application in the root
# of your URL. This is not compatible with more than one application.
#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteRule ^/$ /wordpress/ [PT]
```

Comment: my bet is that this was caused by Wordpress itself and you've just circumvented this behavior now. Take a look at your wordpress settings and the url you've defined there